# date number format to Convert month string format in node js

Tags: node.js, date-formatting

Date 8-1-20  this is the date I want to convert into like this date format.

```
 let formatedDate_cd = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',{
      day:'2-digit',
      month:'long',
      year:'numeric'
    }).format(close_date_)
    console.log(formatedDate_cd.split(" ").join("-"));
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

best way to format a date

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date("8-1-20");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB',{
      day:'2-digit',
      month:'long',
      year:'numeric'
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**output**

01 August 2020